# Underscore template retrieve the value of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, underscore.js

I can retrieve the value of input type text using this

```
<input type="text" 
       value="<%= departureLocation %>" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="departureLocation" 
       name="departureLocation" />
```

but why cannot I retrieve value of textarea using the same way.

```
 <textarea value="<%= eventDescription %>" 
           class="form-control" 
           name="eventDescription" 
           id="eventDescription">
 </textarea>
```

Is there any different  way to retrieve value for textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your content between the tags as in:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="eventDescription" id="eventDescription">
    <%= eventDescription %>
</textarea>
```